# How safe is my Nexus 6 with Android 7.1.1 and the possible latest update (Oct 5th 2017)?

Tags: security, 7.1-nougat, nexus-6

I found my old Nexus 6. No SIM in it, just connects to the Internet via my home wifi.

I've tried to catch the latest updates, upgrades, and security patches, then I realized, unless I doing something "big" like changing rom, or whatever it is called, which I definitely do not want, I stucked with 7.1.1 and its latest security update Oct.5th 17.

My question is it safe to use?

Nothing special sensitive there, but I would like to log in to Google Play with my account to download and by some apps

Comment: That depends mainly on the app you use. If you often try out new apps from PlayStore (or other sources) there is a chance that you may encounter an app that uses one of the vulnerabilities to gain root and installs malware on your system. However if you just use existing apps from known developers and disable Bluetooth (there some vulnerabilities in the last years) on the device the risk of getting infected should be manageable. As you can always go back as Google provides the firmware images I would recommend to test LineageOS for your device.

Comment: Rober, many thx for you instant answer. I am just doing Recovery Mode/Wipe Data Factory Reset. After that I would like to set to connect my home Wifi, then add my Google Account, then buy 2-3 well known application via Google Play. No sideloads, just a few well known app from Google Play.